# UTC timings only in datetimepicker in IOS?

Tags: ios, datepicker

I am using a datetimepicker in iOS on which I need to show timings only in UTC format. I tried it with:

```
[timePicker setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

but it's not working. Can anybody point me how can I achieve this?

Comment: `UIDatePicker` only shows the time in the appropriate format for the user's locale. You can't change that format. BTW - what is "UTC format"? Update your question with an example of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

get current UTC time you can use below code

```
[timePicker setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]]; // GMT and UTC have same time
```